# Error with multiple queries for createPages in gatsby-node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I've tried to format this in every way I can think of:

const { projects, blogs }, const { data } then calling it via data.projects...

Could someone point out an error in my code?

The error says Syntax Error: Expected Name, found ":".

```
{
      projects: allMarkdownRemark(
        filter: { frontmatter: { type: { eq: "project" } } }
```

Thanks

Full Code:

```
const path = require("path")

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const result = await graphql(`
    {
      projects: allMarkdownRemark(
        filter: { frontmatter: { type: { eq: "project" } } }
      ) {
        nodes {
          frontmatter {
            slug
          }
        }
      }
      blogs: projects: allMarkdownRemark(
        filter: { frontmatter: { type: { eq: "blog" } } }
      ) {
        nodes {
          frontmatter {
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  result.data.projects.allMarkdownRemark.nodes.forEach(node => {
    actions.createPage({
      path: "/projects/" + node.frontmatter.slug,
      component: path.resolve("./src/templates/project-details.js"),
      context: { slug: node.frontmatter.slug },
    })
  })

  result.data.blogs.allMarkdownRemark.nodes.forEach(node => {
    actions.createPage({
      path: "/blogs/" + node.frontmatter.slug,
      component: path.resolve("./src/templates/blog-details.js"),
      context: { slug: node.frontmatter.slug },
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are aliasing `allMarkdownRemark` as `projects` and `blogs` so your nested structure should be:

```
const path = require("path")

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const result = await graphql(`
    {
      projects: allMarkdownRemark(
        filter: { frontmatter: { type: { eq: "project" } } }
      ) {
        nodes {
          frontmatter {
            slug
          }
        }
      }
      blogs: allMarkdownRemark(
        filter: { frontmatter: { type: { eq: "blog" } } }
      ) {
        nodes {
          frontmatter {
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  result.data.projects.nodes.forEach(node => {
    actions.createPage({
      path: "/projects/" + node.frontmatter.slug,
      component: path.resolve("./src/templates/project-details.js"),
      context: { slug: node.frontmatter.slug },
    })
  })

  result.data.blogs.nodes.forEach(node => {
    actions.createPage({
      path: "/blogs/" + node.frontmatter.slug,
      component: path.resolve("./src/templates/blog-details.js"),
      context: { slug: node.frontmatter.slug },
    })
  })
}
```

Your new nested structure omits the `allMarkdownRemark` node. In addition, you had a typo in the second aliasing (`blogs`).

Comment: I love you, very very much!